# Github convert existing repo to a fork

Tags: git, github, git-fork

My organisation has a main repo called `org/A.git`. I forked it as `me/A.git` to Github first. My organisation admin made `org/A.git` private, which broke the fork. He then changed settings which would allow forking private repositories. `me/A.git` is still not a fork but a simple clone. How can I make `me/A.git` a fork again, without having to:

1. Fork `org/A.git` again which would result in `me/A-1.git`.
2. Delete `me/A.git`.
3. Rename `me/A-1.git` to `me/A.git`.
4. Push local changes to the new `me/A.git`.

I want to avoid the above 4 steps because I have additional contributors as well as branches in the original `me/A.git` and taking care of all that is just cumbersome for something which seems to be so simple.

Answer (score 8):

This is very, very, very old... However, I recently faced a similar circumstance myself, and contacted GitHub Support. For me, it wasn't that it was a fork originally and then it was broken, but rather I created my own repo manually before understanding what a fork was (still new to Git). GitHub Support confirmed there was no way to do it, unfortunately.

The quote from them:

> Thanks for reaching out! Sorry for the trouble, but it isn't possible to attach a repository as a fork of another in this kind of situation -- repositories can't move from one fork network to another, or to a network they were not originally created from.

Comment: thank you I was looking for this since I had exactly the same problem. it would seem that this would be something that existed

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can. But the four steps you describe probably take less time than the time it took to post here. :-)

For step 4, how about `git push --all origin`?

Comment: The 4 steps are the easy part, the paragraph after that is the hard part. One may have a list of contributors with different rights. It's just hard to believe that it's not possible to make an existing clone a fork of another repository.

Comment: Have you tried contacting GitHub support? They may be able to help you out, even if it's not possible via the UI.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that probably should be the accepted answer haha. I'll leave this open in case someone comes up with a better answer.