# How to make the duplicate repository as fork of the original repository from other organization

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-fork

I have two different Organizations org1 and org2.

each have a repository (org1 -> repo1 and org2 -> repo2)

repo2 is duplicate of repo1 in my case. Unfortunately repo2 is not a fork of repo1.

Please let me know if there is way to make repo2 as fork of repo1 without deleting it

Answer (score 0):

Forking process can be initiated only from the parent repository. Also as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56086243/10155936) no such feature exists.

You can fork repo1 from org1 and transfer the forked repo's organization to org2.

Follow this [article](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/transferring-a-repository#transferring-a-repository-owned-by-your-organization) to transfer ownership of the repository.

---

As pointed out by [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd), the duplicate repo2's(in org2) issues and pull requests would be missing in the new fork of repo1 (in org2).

You can contact **GitHub** [support](https://support.github.com/) for further information on this.

Comment: Moving a new forked repo2 to org2 means that the new repo2 loose all issues and pull requests from the old (the current) repo2.